# 403 error on Wordpress while using Woocommerce Export

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[whi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9F4c.png)

Hello There,

I am facing some issue in my WordPress website. When i try to export woo-commerce products with the Generate CSV button. The exporting process stats but it stuck in the middle of the loading. i have checked the error via inspect element on the Console tab and it shows 403 error. Image is attached for the error logs. Is there anyone who can help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using any cache plugin? If so please disable it and check once again is it working.

Comment: No i am not using any cache plugin. i also tried after disabling all the plugins but no change. i am still getting same error.

Comment: How many products you are trying to export. Try to chunk and only export very few say only first 5 products and see what happening.

Comment: i disabled all products and now tried to export only one product but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably late to answer, but: 
I have **disabled** *mod security* in my cpanel hosting settings and it worked. 
admin-ajax.php was the reason for 403 error. 
Hope it can help anyone else still looking for a solution.